# Dynamically loadedAssemblies for Xamarin.Forms for Android do not find Renderer

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms

I am programing a client server application for android with Xamarin.Forms. this application should be able to load additional control elements during connection the server.

I successfully found a way to download the assemblies from the server, load them via Assembly.Load() and run code of that.

My current problem is that I have two types of assemblies. Some portable Xamarin.Forms extensions as well as the corresponding Android Assemblies which contains the renderers for the portable 'controls'.

Because the renderers are associated to the Xamarin.Forms 'controls' via Code like this

`[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyNewControl), typeof(MyNewControlRenderer)]`

every app must run

`Forms.Init(this, bundle);`

in the 'OnCreate()' method of the MainActivity.
This forms Init can only be called once for the applictaion because a second call will do nothing once the initialization is done.
I must confess that the following is dirty code but I did not found an official way so be patient to me.
I found out via investigation of the Xamarin.Forms code that this 'Init()' method is calling in fact

`Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(new[]{ typeof(ExportRendererAttribute), typeof(ExportCellAttribute), typeof(ExportImageSourceHandlerAttribute) });`

So, i used Reflection to call this function again after loading all my extra assemblies.
after that the usage of the extra controls worked for the first time.
But something happened after that an now, when I use some of that controls I will get an Exception

```
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md559d725e3280243c70c47dd021f85c3f6.MyNewControlRenderer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/MyApp.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/MyApp, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.onClick(ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.java:30)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread`
```

So my two major questions are:
1) What is there an official way to extend the Xamarin.Forms-controls via dynamically loaded assemblies on android, if any?
2) if there is no such way what can I do to fix my issue in on or another, not official, way?

This is my first question and english is not my native language so maybe I did some mistakes, for sure I forgot some relevant information to give. Please correct me where required and I am looking forward for some comments.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What is there an official way to extend the Xamarin.Forms-controls via dynamically loaded assemblies on android, if any? 2) if there is no such way what can I do to fix my issue in on or another, not official, way?

If I understand it correctly, what you need is to create your own [Plugin for Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents) and manage the assemblies loading via nuget package.

You can download the Plugin For Xamarin Templates from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.PluginForXamarinTemplates). And for this template, there is a template named `Control plugins for Xamarin.Forms`, which fit your requirement.

For usage of `Control plugins for Xamarin.Forms`, you can refer to [Creating Control Plugins for Xamarin Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbsKGxo6d74).

**Update:**

It is not possible to inject your custom Renderer at Runtime and use it without any problem. When you are using your custom control, CLR will try to load the renderer class of that control anyway, but because your assembly was loaded at runtime. The metadata of your assembly is never available to the system.Thus the system can never find your renderer class.

Comment: Maybe my description was not exact enough. I don't want to create a plugin which can be added during development. I want to extend the app functionality at runtime. In fact the app itself has a limited function.

Comment: The app should connect to a server and download the corresponding software version. the run a main function within these assembles. This mechanism should provide an easy deployment of the right software version in a closed environment without a connection to the internet. furthermore the app should be able to connect to different servers with different software versions (one at a given time). this should help the customers of my company to reduce the need of manual deployments on up to 300 devices.

Comment: It is not possible to do it at runtime, please check my update.